# Check if a string begins with chars '23' or not - Regex

Tags: regex

My need is to write a simple regex what helps me to check whether the string beginning with the chars '23' or not. If it begins with this string it's okay, if not I'll drop it.

I tried to implement the following regular expression but I think it's not works perfectly.
(^23)

Would you have any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you try it out instead of "assuming" (thinking) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the command you thought works properly. `grep ^23 file` does it:

```
$ cat a
23aaa
aa23
aaa
$ grep ^23 a
23aaa
```